# Set the FilterOn property in form_open

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to set a filter of an continuous form in Access VBA.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
      
    Dim filter As String
    filter = "1 = 0"  ' "1=0" is just for testing purpurses
    Me.filter = filter
    Me.FilterOn = True
    Debug.Print Me.FilterOn & "; " & Me.filter


end sub
```

The output is:

```
False; 1 = 0
```

and the filter is not used.

Is there a way to set and activate the filter before the form is shown?

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue - the filter is applied. Something else is going on.

Comment: FilterOn is true in your case?

Comment: Yep, it's true in debug.

Comment: I found out what the problem was. See my answer. Thank you for trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the reason is. I use a framework where I set the recordsource later. While there is no recordsource, "Me.FilterOn = True" simply does not work. The following code does work:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  
  Me.RecordSource = "select * from MyTable"
  
  Dim filter As String
  filter = "1 = 0"  ' "1=0" is just for testing purpurses
  Me.filter = filter
  Me.FilterOn = True
  Debug.Print Me.FilterOn & "; " & Me.filter

end sub
```

and the output is:

```
True; 1 = 0
```